# What would Dijkstra's shortest path algorithm complexity be with the following data structure?

Tags: graphs, algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, shortest-path

Considering $n$ number of pieces of data, what would Dijkstra's shortest path algorithm time complexity be if it was stored using a data structure with following properties?

• delete the record with the minimum value of the key (complexity $O(log n)$);

• decrease the key of some record (complexity $O(1)$);

• find the record with the minimum value of the key (complexity $O(1)$);

• insert a new record (complexity $O(1)$).

I think it would be $O(nlogn)$, but am having trouble proving it. Does anyone have suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just hand you the solution; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284/98) for tips on asking questions about exercise problems. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?

Comment: Our [reference question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/23593/is-there-a-system-behind-the-magic-of-algorithm-analysis) may be of help.